# Proving $\log{(xy)}=\log{(x)}+\log{(y)}$ for fractional/rational exponents

Tags: logarithms, fractions

I'm very new to math, and I wanted to go back to basics and learn everything on my own. I know that $\log{(xy)}=\log{(x)}+\log{(y)}$  for all real numbers. The rationale is easy to explain for integers.
Say your logarithm is in base $2$. And say you're adding $\log_2(4)$ and $\log_2$(8).
$\log_2(4)=2$, because $2^2$ is $4$.
$\log_2$(8) is $3$, because $2^3=8$.
Now if we multiply $2^2\cdot 2^3$ and expand, it's $(2\cdot 2)\cdot (2\cdot 2\cdot 2)$. The number of "twos" here are $2+3$, so it's $2^{(2+3)}$.
However, it's harder to prove the same for fractional exponents (in whatever form, improper or proper).
The only thing I can sus out is that all can be rewritten in exponential form. Example, $11^{3/4} $ is $(\sqrt[3]{11})^4$, and $12^{1/2}$=$\sqrt{12}^{1}$.

I can't figure this out. If someone can help, it would be great. Thank you.

To further iterate, I should've asked to prove the index rule of creating a number with a fractional exponent, and to prove it follows all the same rules integer exponents do.

Comment: There's a beginners set of (A-Level) lessons on exponentials and logarithms at http://www.numberwonder.co.uk/Pages/Page9031.html

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please write out you question using: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.